# Why were obsolete comment flags declined for an addressed issue?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

The user raised [some valid concern here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873612/answer-an-udp-packet/24873835#comment38640691_24873835) under my answer, so I addressed it after a bit of thinking. Having that done, I had flagged the two comments for removal as they became obsolete, but the flags got declined.

Was it justified in this case? When shall we flag comments then as obsolete? I thought noisy discussions should be gone if the agreement is reached and the answer reflects that discussion with an edit.

Note that, I even removed my comments in the middle, so it was also partially broken already.

Comment: Could you share with us the reasons the moderators provided for declining these flags?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: no reason provided.

Comment: Really? How strange. In my experience, moderators always leave a comment (visible in your flag list) when declining a flag. Can you double-check, just in case?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I can assure you that I checked that one, but I have just done it again to make sure.

Comment: Perhaps they find those flags superfluous as there are only so few comments... still, removeing the comments is usefull for the next reader.

Comment: [Because it's Tuesday.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266282/19679)

Comment: Comment flags are very light-weight, @Frédéric - moderators either delete or dismiss, there is no decline reason option.

Comment: @Shog9, true, I missed these were comment flags. I'll be right back, looks like I forgot my brains in the car.

Comment: @FinalContest did you just make that edit that I rolled back?

Comment: @Tanner: yes, it well explains my opinion (cough-cough, **frustration**) about how nonsensical moderators can be. The comments are still not deleted, and the whole discussion has wasted everyone's time and more to come (hello readers?). It should have been a no-brainer removal in the first place. I will write to the community VP about this. I am pretty shocked it wastes so much time from everyone to get simple things done, and it is impossible in the end. Let us see what he will think about it.

Comment: @FinalContest I'm staying out of this one... good luck!

Comment: @Sam: any reason why you can **not** read? The initially upvoted question got downvotes after the heated discussion in the comments which will turn it into oblivion anyway even though the original content has not changed a bit. The downvotes only after the heated discussion is bigger vandalism. Again, the content has not changed a bit, yet someone turned the upvote into downvote all of a sudden. I would whole-heartedly delete this question in the first place, but it is not possible with an answer now.

Comment: @FinalContest Ah yeah, sorry missed that.

Comment: @Sam: the ridiculous thing is that the answer got unexplained downvotes as well over there after this thread... meta is a nons... not-mature place to discuss issues at, sorry.

Comment: @Sam: yes, I know, I have never thought I would get unexplained downvotes, though for such a well-worked out answer after discussing an irrelevant topic there with regards to downvotes: an obsolete comment. That is just really ridiculous revenge.

Comment: @FinalContest Maybe it was a result of that edit?

Answer (score 9):

First off, asking for a reason for dismissed comment flags is a pretty huge waste of time. All comment flags should be understood as declined for the same reason, which might be worded:

> A moderator disagreed with your assessment of the flagged comments' value and refrained from deleting them.

If you feel strongly that they should be removed, then use the "other" option and explain *why*.

Second, if you're trying to clear out an entire comment thread where you've already deleted *your* part of the conversation, then just *flag the post* - and again, explain the situation.

Finally, just because you deleted *your* comments doesn't necessarily mean that someone else's comments are obsolete. It's great that you thought better of getting into an unproductive and overly-personal argument - seriously - but if someone felt there was a concern worth noting then that's their prerogative; if you truly wish to make the concerns *obsolete*, then addressing them directly **in an edit** would be a good option. A follow-up comment noting that they've been addressed may even prompt the commenter to remove his own comments, thus removing the need for moderator intervention entirely!

Comment: Pretty nonsensical reply to me. It is writing that we should not care about cleaning up threads, come on ... If you, as a moderator, have no clue about what you are doing, just do not do it, and let it with people who actually do care about cleaning up do the job, e.g. gold badge holders. Waiting for other people when they 90% do not come back is also practice-free advice. What is even more amusing, you call others waste of time, when you still waste others' time by not cleaning up, but suggesting that I should leave a comment and wait for others to clean up.

Comment: If you care about cleaning up a thread, then actually clean it up - don't spend 1s dumping it in a moderator's lap and then 100x as long asking why it wasn't done to your satisfaction. You get out what you put in.

Comment: @Final, I believe Shog will be the last one to say that :) More seriously, "if you're trying to clear out an entire comment thread where you've already deleted your part of the conversation, then just flag the post - and again, explain the situation" does not read like "just leave them alone" to me.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: what else to do there? I removed my part, and the answer got updated.... oopsie, "accidentally" with the issue in the comments? How come? So surprising, isn't it? Let us decline it. I expect some intelligence and self-activity  from moderators, too, especially if everything is there. What is not clear that at the time of flagging, the post got an edit? What else should I write into the custom reason? Dear moderator, you are sexy today, or what? Isn't it self-evident that for an obsolete flag the history and edit have to be checked?

Comment: Again, you get what you put in. There was nothing in the edit, in further commentary, or in the flag itself to indicate that you'd handled the issue; comments are not important enough to waste any time trying to investigate non-obvious issues. PS: Ben (the guy you were conversing with) is pretty much *always here* - complaining that he might not see your comment is silly.

Comment: @Final, my understanding of the situation if that flagging individual comments is not the right course of action here. You could raise a custom flag on the answer instead, and explain there that you want the comments to be cleaned up because you have updated the answer (then again, leaving a comment to the same effect, as suggested, will not hurt either). Just keep in mind that flag *could* also be rejected, but this time you will have an idea of why.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: explaining _what_? The answer got an edit, and 1-2 minutes later the corresponding comment was flagged for obsolete? It is clear that the moderator who declined had no any interest to do the job right, and instead, did it wrong off-hand rather than skipping the job.

Comment: @Final, something like *I updated my answer following the commenter's rightful advice, could the comment thread be cleaned up?* would work I think. Re: you opinion on moderators, do you have an idea of the number of flags they have to handle per hour?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: why would it work? They already have the edit date there available _right away_. Why would it help to repeat that? They should check the validity _anyway_, otherwise they will delete potentially useful comments based on some "random" reasoning. It is unbelievable not to stand corrected here, no matter who did it, but what is even more amusing, the comments are still not gone and the answer talks about time wasting... how ironic.

Comment: @Final I think the point here is that the less time a moderator has to spend on validating your flag, the more likely it will be marked as helpful. You could have used the **Edit Summary** to describe your edit instead of leaving it empty and ending up with the standard "x characters added to body".

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: since you edited your previous comment after I wrote mine, here goes it in a separate: I do **NOT** care how many flags they "have" to handle. If they cannot handle certain flags, they should skip the those. They should not do bad job just because they "have to". Please vote on my proposal to give this rights to gold badge holders if you want to get it solved.

Comment: No, they should not. Comment flags are, by and large, a *massive* waste of their time even at best - if they're spending any more time than it takes to glance at the comment thread and click either "delete" or "dismiss", then they're doing it wrong; there are bigger fish to fry.

Comment: @Stijn: huh? Should I write poem, too, for changing literally a couple of characters? I think this will end up again in writing to the community VP... It seems I cannot get a simple comment deletion done for completely obsolete comments any other way. I will not beg more than spending a lot of time here again for trivial things. It is ludicrous. Today, I have also finished cleaning up posts with flags. -1 person with 3000+ flags there.

Comment: Once upon a time, we had quality flaggers 'round here. They wrote verse, literally poetry, in hope of beguiling the moderators. Kids these days...

Comment: @Final you need to put yourself in the position of the one handling the flags. When I get support mails of co-workers that are missing details which I *could* get by running a few database queries, I email them back asking for the details, because it's too time consuming and I could spend my time in better ways. I have voted on your proposal because I do agree that we could lessen the workload of moderators, but it's useless to spend energy and get fed up like this over the current situation.

Comment: @Shog9: I remember those days.  It was a kinder gentler world, back then... The land was full of milk and honey.  Then the peasants came.