# Why were my [obsolete] flags declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I flagged the comments under [this closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133455/how-to-do-a-tutorial-for-beginning-user-of-my-app) as obsolete. They all have to do with closing the question:

[image: flagged comments]

and were thus obsolete/no longer relevant. Yet, they were declined:

[image: declined flags]

Why?

Comment: The question should be deleted, that will solve your issue with the obsolete comments.

Comment: @slugster that doesn't change the fact that the flags should've been accepted and the comments deleted.

Comment: I once read somewhere here on meta that in this case, you could flag other and state "The whole tread is obsolete because ..." although my flags (on a different question) have been recently declined. I thus refrain from flagging comments unless they are clearly hostile, see also [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266395/why-were-obsolete-comment-flags-declined-for-an-addressed-issue?rq=1)

Comment: An SO user went through the trouble explaining why the question is off topic.  Very hard to see why it would be "obsolete", the OP did nothing to fix his question and it is still off topic.

Comment: Mods have enough flags to deal with. Dealing with obsolete flags are last on the list. And flagging that a bunch of times on a question that's closed and heading for deletion is a huge waste of time. Why waste everybody's time?